# Reading JSON from a URL in AngularJS using $http.get

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, json

I've written a Flask back-end for an application I'm developing. In short, when calling *http://localhost:5000/allsongs/* it returns something like (or very similar to) the following:

```
[["King And Lionheart", "Of Monsters And Men", "My Head Is An Animal", "mp3"], ["Just One Yesterday", "Fall Out Boy", "Save Rock And Roll", "mp3"], ["Laughter Lines", "Bastille", "All This Bad Blood", "mp3"]]
```

I'm trying to write a web-app using AngularJS that reads the data from that URL and uses `ng-repeat` to make a list that I can search through. So far, I have written this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="myApp">

<body>

<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('Songs', function Songs($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:5000/allmusic').then(function(response) {
      $scope.songs = response;
    });
  }
    );
</script>

<input placeholder="Search..." type="text" ng-model="search" />


<div ng-controller="Songs">
<p>{{songs}}</p>
</div>
<p ng-repeat="song in songs | filter:search | orderBy:name">{{ song }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

All that shows up when I load the page is the search field at the top of the page.

Also, when I refresh the page I see my Flask server being called, so I know the `$http.get` is working somewhat.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Oops, copied and pasted the ng-repeat wrong, it actually reads:`<div ng-controller="Songs"><p ng-repeat="song in songs | filter:search | orderBy:name">{{ song }}</p></div>`

Comment: Shouldn't you use $scope.songs = JSON.parse(response)

Comment: Have you done a console.log on the $http.get response inside the then function to verify you are getting the data you expect?

Comment: @Ludo - you do not need to parse the response if it is already in json format from the server. It will be directly usable and assignable in Angular.

Comment: @DanielNalbach - I added a console.log for the response, but I found this: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/allmusic. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`, which on the removal of the console.log was still there. Simply put, the log didn't do anything, but that error was there.

Comment: Apparently this is a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be an CORS issue when you render HTML not at server side. So you have two options.

1. Add some router that return `index.html` with all Angular code you need.
2. Add some header response changes.

Sadly I have no experience with Flask, but at Node.js the second solution may looks like that

```
app.use((req,res)=>{
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    req.next();
  });
```

Comment: Finally! I fixed it! You were right, it was a CORS issue. I mucked around with the JavaScript for a bit but to no avail. Instead I used something I found called [flask-cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It basically adds the right headers for you.